# OpenCV Machine Learning output Type I and Type II errors

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

It is my first time to use machine learning functions in OpenCV. I used Boost algorithm and I think it works well. However, it was pretty annoying that the function `calc_error` only gives error, without error type. what I meant is:

> Type I False positive error, false alarm

or

> Type II Missing a target

Can OpenCV also gives the error type? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`predict`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboost-predict) on your test instances, loop over all test instances and compare the outcome with the true class to find Type 1/Type 2 error yourself (or precision and accuracy, related concepts which are more common in Machine Learning).

Some pseudocode expressing this idea:

```
true_positive = 0
false_positive = 0
true_negative = 0
false_negative = 0

For i in 1..N:
    test_instance = test_set[i]

    true_class = labels[i]
    predicted_class = predict(test_instance, ... )

    if true_class = True and predicted_class == True
        true_positive += 1
    elseif true_class == False and predicted_class == True
        false_positive += 1
    elseif true_class == True and predicted_class == False
        false_negative += 1
    elseif true_class == False and predicted_class == False
        true_negative += 1
    end

type_I_error = false_positive/N
type_II_error = false_negative/N
```